# Preserve array index inside react clone child loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, closures

I have strange issue with index not being preserved while looping and cloning 
react children. Here is code in question :

```
// Table Body component
const DataBody = ({
  resource,
  children,
  ids,
  data,
  ...rest
}) => (
  <tbody {...rest}>
    {ids.map((id, rowIndex) => (
      <TableRow key={id}>
        {React.Children.map(children, (field, index) => {
          return (
            <Cell
              key={`${id}-${field.props.source || index}`}
              record={data[id]}
              {...{ field, index, resource }}
            />
          )
        })}
      </TableRow>
    ))}
  </tbody>
)

// Table Cell component
const Cell = ({ classes, field, index, record, resource, theme, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <td className={mapToCSSModule(classes, theme)} {...rest}>
      {React.cloneElement(field, { record, resource, index })}
    </td>
  )
}

// Table data component
const IndexField = ({
  format,
  index,
  tag: Tag = 'span',
  ...props
}) => {
  const no = index + 1
  return <Tag {...props}>{format ? format(no) : no}</Tag>
}
```

Now, the problem is that index is always 0 inside the IndexField but in Cell it's value is OK, like when we are lost inside a loop/closure which always returns last value of the passed variable.
Is there a clean way to handle elegantly this ?

EDIT: Added main component that is looping trough the data, note that this is streamed down version (original is fully working, only thing that is non-functional is the index).

Comment: I dont see any loop here?

Comment: It's the main component which uses React.Children.map .. I'm adding it to the code example right now..

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, rowIndex works flawelessly so I've implemented that instead of child index.. here is the code:

```
// Table Body component
const DataBody = ({
  resource,
  children,
  ids,
  data,
  startingNo, // First item index (data is paged on the server)
  ...rest
}) => (
  <tbody {...rest}>
    {ids.map((id, rowIndex) => (
      <TableRow key={id}>
        {React.Children.map(children, (field, index) => {
          return (
            <Cell
              key={`${id}-${field.props.source || index}`}
              index={startingNo + rowIndex}
              {...{ field, resource }}
            />
          )
        })}
      </TableRow>
    ))}
  </tbody>
)
```